# Can't ping hostnames and IPv6 after router restart

Tags: dns, hostname, router

This happened after a router restart.
(no idea if this is relevant but my Windows PC also reverted the DNS settings to an old local server I tested)

I noticed the issue when I ssh'ed to my homelab server.

The custom welcome script hangs on:

```
`hostname -I | /usr/bin/cut -d " " -f 1` and `wget -q -O - http://icanhazip.com/ | tail`
```

It used to output a ipv4 and ipv6 address.

The /etc/resolv.conf had the exact timestamp of the router restart, so I was focusing on this config. I feel like I'm missing my router's IP on the first line.

Commands (I killed commands after 2 minutes without response):

```
kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup www.google.com
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.106
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.105
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.104
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.147
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.103
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 172.253.120.99
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400c:c01::6a
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400c:c01::67
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400c:c01::69
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:400c:c01::68

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com(wj-in-x67.1e100.net (2a00:1450:400c:c01::67)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
367 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 374791ms

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 2a00:1450:400c:c01::67
PING 2a00:1450:400c:c01::67(2a00:1450:400c:c01::67) 56 data bytes
^C
--- 2a00:1450:400c:c01::67 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12284ms

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 172.253.120.106
PING 172.253.120.106 (172.253.120.106) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=23.5 ms
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=18.8 ms
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from 172.253.120.106: icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=18.6 ms
^C
--- 172.253.120.106 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.357/19.426/23.534/1.841 ms

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
search telenet.be
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 2a02:1800:100::44:1
nameserver 2a02:1800:100::44:2

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# I removed all the comments for this post.
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

# I edited this during setup but still does the job:
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8

kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

edit:

```
kevin@raspberrypi:~ $ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (172.253.120.105), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  1.599 ms  1.696 ms  1.754 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  108.170.241.225 (108.170.241.225)  30.000 ms 142.251.255.38 (142.251.255.38)  24.602 ms 142.250.224.130 (142.250.224.130)  24.438 ms
 9  108.170.241.141 (108.170.241.141)  29.613 ms 108.170.241.205 (108.170.241.205)  29.620 ms 108.170.241.237 (108.170.241.237)  29.355 ms
10  216.239.42.213 (216.239.42.213)  29.938 ms 216.239.41.49 (216.239.41.49)  29.745 ms  29.528 ms
11  142.250.227.197 (142.250.227.197)  30.911 ms  30.768 ms 216.239.43.129 (216.239.43.129)  24.435 ms
12  64.233.175.102 (64.233.175.102)  29.005 ms 142.251.69.115 (142.251.69.115)  30.636 ms *
13  172.253.67.149 (172.253.67.149)  24.060 ms * 172.253.67.145 (172.253.67.145)  86.527 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  wd-in-f105.1e100.net (172.253.120.105)  22.514 ms  29.539 ms  27.640 ms
```

Comment: `traceroute` would be better. However, I expect you have no global IPv6 address on your local host.

Comment: I haven't configured a static IPv6 as I don't exactly know how it works

Comment: You are going into confusion territory. IPv6 addresses can be applied automatically, no need for static. So again, I expect you have no global IPv6 address on your local host, hence the traceroute request. We would also expect IPv6 details of your router.

Comment: @Bib -  Thank you for the explanation, I've edited the original post with traceroute to google.com